# Need to import custom fields of product in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to insert some custom fields of product into a table. But When I upload the CSV file then it shows me error as 
"Column names: "_custom_option_tier_customer_group", "_custom_option_tier_price", "_custom_option_tier_price_qty" are invalid"

And I have these custom fields

[image]

So can you please help me how I can import the fields and bypass the validation error.

Answer (score 0):

You Should give the following fields correct,
    1. _custom_option_type
    2. _custom_option_title
    3. _custom_option_is_required
    4. _custom_option_row_title
    5. _custom_option_row_price
    6. _custom_option_row_sku

I thinks this will helps u...

Comment: No.. these are my custom(own defined) fields and want to store in different table in DB.